# Marks for upvoted comments disappear when answering

Tags: bug, android-app

On Android, when I visit a question, vote on comments, look at an answer and come back, my votes are gone. If I try to vote again, I'm told that I can't vote twice.

Comment: I believe this has been fixed around v1.0.77~v1.0.83. I remembered the changelog, but forgot the exact version.